# Showing only the content of a file from a directory(given as parameter ) or his subdirectories which has .txt extension, using grep

Tags: linux, grep

I managed to do this using find:

```
find 'directory' -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

I have no clue how can I do it using grep.Tried to do it thousand times.

Comment: Although I provided an answer, I have to admit that this is a confusing question. What is meant by "a file", and why do we have to use `grep` to display content. It's normally not the right tool for that (exceptions exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the content of a file with `grep`, you can search for the empty regular expression `grep "" file.txt`, or the "beginning of line" regular expression `grep ^ file.txt`.

How I understand it, the directory is given as a parameter. If that is so:

```
grep ^ $(find $1 -name '*.txt')
```

or

```
find $1 -name '*.txt' -exec grep ^ {} \;
```

The problem with both solutions is that they display the content of **all** text files, not "**a** file" as the question wants. The first solution also prints the names of the text files if more than one text file is found. Finally, my first solution breaks if too many text files are found; `xargs` helps in this case.

Comment: that `$(find)` also breaks with other filenames. GNU grep and some others has `grep -H` to always print the filename, even if there's only one file. But you can usually emulate that by adding a dummy file, e.g. `grep ^ /dev/null {}`

Comment: I had not taken into account that `grep ^ $(find ... )` breaks if nothing is found. Or rather, it will hang waiting for input on stdin, and the user might sit there scratching their head. Good idea to add the dummy.

Comment: Mostly I meant the command substitution breaks if there's filenames with whitespace (or glob characters, to a lesser extent)

Comment: I keep falling in this trap.

Comment: welcome to the wonderful land of *nix and the shell language.

Answer (score 1):

At least with GNU grep (which is probably the implementation that you have, since you tagged the question *Linux*), you can use the `--include`  option to limit searched files by glob. Combining that with an empty pattern to simulate `cat`:

```
grep -hr --include='*.txt' '' directory
```

The `-h` turns off default prefixing of the filename to the matched results.